# Rewrite Wordpress url in CUSTOM POST TYPE

Tags: php, wordpress, url, wordpress-theming

I have horoscope post type, where I have 4 categories (yearly, monthly, lovely and weekly horoscope) every post have 12 editors - 12 signs.
I need that URL structure:

1. In Yearly I need this url: http://domain.com/post-type/taxonomy/year
2. In Monthly I need this url:
   http://domain.com/post-type/taxonomy/month/year
3. In Lovely I need this url:
   http://domain.com/post-type/taxonomy/month/year
4. In Weekly I need this url: http://domain.com/post-type/taxonomy

In Yearly I have many years, in monthly and lovely I have many years and many month, in weekly just on page that edit every week.

At first I think that "taxonomy" - it will be parent category of taxonomy, "month" - it will be child category of taxonomy and "year" - it will be post.
But when create in on taxonomy the same name of category their slug became "month-1, month-2" and the same when I create the same post name in post type.
So this solution doesn't work.

Now I want to create 4 post type and in each post type rewrite url, like that:

1. In Yearly I need that in url show:
   http://domain.com/horoscope/post-type/year-of-post create and no slug of post
2. In Monthly and Lovely I need that in url show:
   http://domain.com/horoscope/post-type/month-of-post-create/year-of-post-create/ and no slug of post
3. In weekly just: http://domain.com/horoscope/weekly/

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow, please take a look at [this](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) and do take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you want help, we are here to help you, not just feed you..

Comment: can u tell me please, what`s wrong with my post?

Comment: Well the main problem, is you are asking for code, and you havn't shown us any effort of trying something yourself..

Comment: I want to know in which way better to code. I sad in wich way I think better code, but maybe someone know how do it better. And help me.

Comment: So at first I want to take advice what structure is better!
And then help with code.

Comment: If you want to know which is better or not, that is primarely opinion based and usually gets your question closed, and in order to get help with code you need actual code..

Comment: I add code to discribe in which situation I pause now.

Answer (score 0):

Now I create 4 post type and rewrite url with this code:

```
global $wp_rewrite;
$kuukausihoroskooppi_structure = '/horoskoopit/kuukausihoroskooppi/%monthnum%/%year%/%kuukausihoroskooppi%';
$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%kuukausihoroskooppi%", '([^/]+)', "kuukausihoroskooppi=");
$wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('kuukausihoroskooppi', $kuukausihoroskooppi_structure, false);
// Add filter to plugin init function
add_filter('post_type_link', 'kuukausihoroskooppi_permalink', 10, 3);
// Adapted from get_permalink function in wp-includes/link-template.php
function kuukausihoroskooppi_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
$post = get_post($post_id);
$rewritecode = array(
    '%year%',
    '%monthnum%',
    '%day%',
    '%hour%',
    '%minute%',
    '%second%',
    $leavename? '' : '%postname%',
    '%post_id%',
    '%category%',
    '%author%',
    $leavename? '' : '%pagename%',
);

if ( '' != $permalink && !in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft')) ) {
    $unixtime = strtotime($post->post_date);

    $category = '';
    if ( strpos($permalink, '%category%') !== false ) {
        $cats = get_the_category($post->ID);
        if ( $cats ) {
            usort($cats, '_usort_terms_by_ID'); // order by ID
            $category = $cats[0]->slug;
            if ( $parent = $cats[0]->parent )
                $category = get_category_parents($parent, false, '/', true) . $category;
        }
        // show default category in permalinks, without
        // having to assign it explicitly
        if ( empty($category) ) {
            $default_category = get_category( get_option( 'default_category' ) );
            $category = is_wp_error( $default_category ) ? '' : $default_category->slug;
        }
    }

    $author = '';
    if ( strpos($permalink, '%author%') !== false ) {
        $authordata = get_userdata($post->post_author);
        $author = $authordata->user_nicename;
    }

    $date = explode(" ",date_i18n('Y F d H i s', $unixtime));
    $rewritereplace =
        array(
            $date[0],
            $date[1],
            $date[2],
            $date[3],
            $date[4],
            $date[5],
            $post->post_name,
            $post->ID,
            $category,
            $author,
            $post->post_name,
        );
    $permalink = str_replace($rewritecode, $rewritereplace, $permalink);
} else { // if they're not using the fancy permalink option
}
return $permalink;
}
```

For Yearly post type I don`t need %monthum% in my url so in that post type in code:

```
$kuukausihoroskooppi_structure = '/horoskoopit/kuukausihoroskooppi/%monthnum%/%year%/%kuukausihoroskooppi%';
```

I remove %month%/ and this post type work good with url http://domain.com/horoscope/post_type/year_of_post/post_slug with template: single-post_type.php
But I don`t need post-slug, so I remove %kuukausihoroskooppi%, but then this page show like archive.php;

But post type Monthly and Lovely wich url with %monthum% is redirect to 404 page and dont show.

What better to do?